# Retrieve metadata only for Google Cloud object using JSON API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to retrieve the metadata *only* for an object in Google Cloud storage. The JSON API discusses this in the docs for the [get method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get), which "[r]etrieves an object or its metadata", but it's not clear how to retrieve the metadata without downloading the actual object, which in my case can be quite large.

The docs for the XML API addresses this point, and for my same reason:

> You **should not** use a GET object request to retrieve general object metadata, because doing so incurs egress charges associated with downloading the entire object.

([from here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object))

But there's no HEAD request in the JSON API. What's the right way to get this info by using the JSON API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to retrieve the metadata only for an object in Google Cloud
>   storage. ...  But there's no HEAD request in the JSON API. What's the
>   right way to get this info by using the JSON API?

The same REST API can return either the object's content or the object's metadata. This is controlled via query parameters. The key query param is `alt=media`. Without this parameter, metadata is returned. With this parameter, content is returned.

Example to obtain an object's content (URL Encoded):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/Public%2Fobject_name?alt=media
```

Example to obtain an object's metadata [no owner or ACL properties] (URL Encoded):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/Public%2Fobject_name
```

Example to obtain an object's full metadata (URL encoded):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/Public%2Fobject_name?projection=full
```

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get)

Python 3.x example using these URLs (no error checking):

```
access_token = ....

headers = {
                "Host": "www.googleapis.com",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
         }

h = httplib2.Http()

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/Public%2Fobject_name?projection=full'

resp, content = h.request(uri=url, method="GET", headers=headers)

print(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: That does seem to do it, thank you. Not entirely comfortable that this isn't documented in the API, but for now I'll go with it!

Comment: Actually, this is documented. I will post another comment later once I get back from lunch as I have to look it up.

Comment: This link documents, `alt=media` and `projection` and a few others: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get

Comment: Bah. I clearly just don't know how to read; I was looking for the "alt=media" in the lists, not in the text of the "Response" section. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the get method is used to retrieve content AND metadata.  If all you want is metadata, then we appear to be able to perform a [list command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) which will return the list of files (if you explicitly name 1 existing file it is only that which will be returned) which appears to include all the metadata for the identified file.